# Как создать свой API для модификаций(модов простыми словами) к игре Roblox?

Tags: mod, roblox

Каким образом я могу создать свой api для игры "Roblox"? Никогда не создавал свой API и решил начать с этой игры, так как много модов создано именно для этой программы(включая шейдеры и тд.). С чего мне начать?